# How to upgrade php curl on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-10.04, curl

I have a web service on 64bit AWS/ubuntu 10.04 machine. Current php ver PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15. Current curl ver: 7.19.7

This Curl version has a memory leak and I need to upgrade to V 7.25.0

apt-get says my version is the latest, On curl download page the last version for Ubuntu is the one I have. There doesnt seem to be an upgraded version available.

How can I upgrade ? I spent hours on Google and couldn't find any information.

Comment: Found it in the answer here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/230529/how-to-install-php-from-source-with-latest-curl-package-on-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Ubuntu 10.04 was released, curl 7.19.7 was a stable and current release. Ubuntu will not upgrade to later versions with new functionality, but they will backport security fixes.

If the memory leak bug in 7.19.7 was of significance, it is likely that the bugfix has been backported by Ubuntu into the curl-version you currently have on your system.

Comment: Thanks. The memory leak is there so it is not the case

Comment: You could try to grab the curl-package from one of the later Ubuntu distributions, but you might end up in a dependency hell.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=curl

Comment: found it here
http://serverfault.com/questions/230529/how-to-install-php-from-source-with-latest-curl-package-on-linux